# What is the openssl command i need to use for this?

Tags: linux, https, certificate, openssl, lighttpd

I need openssl to return two files ssl.pem and ca.crt

the ssl.pem is for my lighttpd webserver to give if they include https instead of http.

the ca.crt is what they must download from my site and then install on their computer.

I am using linux-mint with openssl installed by default.. I will transfer lots of my files over to a debian-based machine

Comment: Do you mean authentication via client SSL certificates?

Comment: humm. ca.crt, the client installs it and talks to my server securly so maybe, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this tutorial](http://knol.google.com/k/openssl-creating-your-own-ca-requesting-and-signing-certs-and-import-them-into#) to generate your own CA and sign certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own CA, consider using [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org)

Comment: can't, i cant setup the email for any of the emails for my domain. (My dad will not include it)